# AES-256-CBC encryption returning different result in Python and PHP

Tags: python, php, encryption, aes

Python Code:

```
import hashlib
import json
import base64
import requests
from Crypto.Cipher import AES


class Adauth:
    def __init__(self):
        self.secret_key = "SSSSSSSSSSSS"
        self.secret_iv = "LLLLLLLLLLLL"
        self.hashed_key = hashlib.sha256(self.secret_key.encode()).hexdigest()[:32]
        self.iv = hashlib.sha256(self.secret_iv.encode()).hexdigest()[:16]

    def encrypt_data(self,data):
        cipher = AES.new(self.hashed_key.encode("utf8"), AES.MODE_CBC, self.iv.encode("utf8"))
        encrypted = cipher.encrypt(data.encode("utf8"))
        return  base64.b64encode(encrypted).decode()


ad = Adauth()
data = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" #16 char
print ("Actual string: ", data)
s = ad.encrypt_data(data)
print("Encrypted string: ",s)
```

Output:

```
Actual string:  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
Encrypted string:  osdKcm6x15VMHf/wHnA0uA==
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$plaintextstr = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA';
$encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
$secret_key = "SSSSSSSSSSSS";
$secret_iv = "LLLLLLLLLLLL";
$key = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_key), 0, 32);
$iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv), 0, 16);
$encrypted_str = openssl_encrypt($plaintextstr, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
echo "Actual string: ".$plaintextstr;
echo "Encrypted string: ".$encrypted_str;
```

Output:

```
Actual string: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
Encrypted string: b3NkS2NtNngxNVZNSGYvd0huQTB1RG4vTVFmbmVhb1B2MTg4QUxpQUlGbz0=
```

I want Python encrypted string same as PHP encrypted string. What is the issue in Python code?

Comment: Your PHP code is not executable. Also, both codes produce different outputs than posted. Fix both please! Now about your bugs: In the PHP code, disable the Base64 encoding of the ciphertext (i.e. remove `base64_encode()`), because this is done *implicitly*. Also disable padding (`OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING`). Then the PHP code returns the same ciphertext as the Python code, s. [`openssl_encrypt()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php).

Comment: thanks it working now. it was padding issue

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the problem is that `openssl_encrypt` returns the result as a Base64-encoded string and you get an unexpected result when you encode it again with `base64_encode()`.

*Note: Originally, I mistakenly thought that it was due to the absence of padding in the Python code. However, as it was pointed out in the comments, the plaintext in your example is 16 bytes which is equal to the AES block size and thus doesn't need any padding.*

### Solution

- Either don't Base64-encode the value returned by `openssl_encrypt` or pass `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` option instead of the zero.
- Optionally, pad the data in the Python code. It is not required if the data is a multiple of `AES.block_size`. However, it might not hurt to have padding there just to be sure that it doesn't fail if the plaintext size changes:

```py
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad

padded_data = pad(data, AES.block_size, 'pkcs7')
cipher = AES.new(self.hashed_key.encode("utf8"), AES.MODE_CBC, self.iv.encode("utf8"))
encrypted = cipher.encrypt(padded_data)
```

#### Sample PHP code

```php
$plaintextstr = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA';
$encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
$secret_key = "SSSSSSSSSSSS";
$secret_iv = "LLLLLLLLLLLL";
$key = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_key), 0, 32);
$iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv), 0, 16);
$encrypted_str = openssl_encrypt($plaintextstr, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
```